# Understanding a line from Fulton's book regarding projective plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, projective-varieties

Here's a paragraph from the book:

[image]

How is he going from $z\neq 0$ to allowing $0$ in the last entry (e.g. $[1:m:0]$)? One way I can see is by taking the Zariski closure of the set since the set was a plane minus a line through the origin union the origin. But why are we doing it?

Edit: I shouldn't use the term 'algebraic closure' in this context

Comment: Yeah basically he's saying the affine line is $\{[x:y:z] \mid y=mx+bz, z\ne  0\}$, and the closure in $\Bbb{P}^2$ is $\{[x:y:z] \mid y=mx+bz\}$. In other words, we get one new point, $[1:m:0]$, when we extend our affine line to the projective plane. The reason to do this is that the affine line ceases to be closed when we include the affine plane into the projective plane, so we need to understand its closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point $(x,y)$ in $\Bbb A^2$ corresponds to a point $[x:y:1]$ in $\Bbb P^2$. In the projective completion of the affine line, the point at infinity has the last coordinate equal to $0$.

This is also valid for any algebraic curve. For instance the  unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in the  affine complex plane has  two points at infinity $[1:\pm i:0]$ in its projective completion, since its homogeneised equation is $x^2+y^2=z^2$.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure that we were indeed taking the closure. So two parallel lines do not intersect, but rather their closures do?

Comment: Well, yes, he's considering the projective closure.